# GCP API Keys Admin role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase) tutorial which states you should add "API Keys Admin role" to the cloud build service account, but I can't find the "API Keys" group in the drop down of the GCP UI. Does anyone know why this is? Do I need to use the command line tool? Has it changed name?

Answer (score 2):

In my view, the "API Keys Admin role" here refers to "serviceAccountKeyAdmin" Role. Because, this is the role which is required to generate Service Account API key.

Details about [serviceAccountKeyAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles) role from official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because my user's language in GCP was Spanish and searching "API keys" wasn't bringing me the result for the service in Spanish (it's **Administrador de claves de API** btw), and if you have something different than English (US) as the language, I would recommend changing it while following docs in English so everything matches.

You can change it by going to the profile settings > Preferences > Language & region > Select: English (United States) > Click Save.

Hope it helps someone ;).